# Transactions not end when application shut down

Tags: java, hibernate, websphere, transactionmanager

I am working Rational Application Developer with Websphere 8.5 and I got this warning message on startup. So, when I try to debug I cannot save any object to db2 with hibernate.

> [8/5/14 10:12:26:026 EEST] 0000004d SharedPool    I   J2CA0086W: Shareable connection MCWrapper id 7d46089c  Managed connection WSRdbManagedConnectionImpl@57aa018c  State:STATE_TRAN_WRAPPER_INUSE Connections being held 1 Used with transaction com.ibm.ws.LocalTransaction.LocalTranCoordImpl@5d96710d;RUNNING;
>    from resource jdbc/WS_Mosip_ATLANTIS was used within a local transaction containment boundary.

Anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

You should rather not use `Sharable` connections, if using from web module. Change the `res-sharing-scope` of the connection to be `Unshareable`. The recommended way to do this is by using a resource reference and looking up the resource reference.

See [Application hangs with J2CA0045E errors and with J2CA0086W warning messages](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21121449) for more details.